# Xcode 6: can I force a push style segue?

Tags: ios

This is an infuriating problem... Xcode 6 and iOS 8 introduced adaptive segues, but they do not degrade gracefully in iOS 7.

Here is the (very common) scenario: I have an iPhone storyboard with a navigation controller with several other view controllers that should be pushed (i.e, slide from the right to the left) when the segue is called. The segues were created with a previous version of Xcode in IB, but upon inspecting them with the attributes inspector I see that the segue type selected is "Show (e.g. Push)".

This produces the push style segue I'm after in iOS 8. However, in iOS 7, the views are presented modally (from the bottom up), and what's worse, they lose their navigation bar. Since it was created in a previous version of Xcode, I tried re-creating the segue in IB to no avail.

I cannot find ANY documentation on this from Apple. How can I force the push style segue for iOS 7 without using the now deprecated Push segue?

Comment: Filed this on Apple's Bug Tracker: 18781268